# ArgumentError: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty. Rails CRUD app,

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm debugging an issue with what should be a fairly simple CRUD application for a course I'm taking. It's turning out to be more difficult than I imagined. I'm attempting to set it in the app so I can go into the question and either choose to edit or delete it. The delete works more or less just fine. But I get the following errors when I click the 'edit' button:

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in QuestionsController#edit - Couldn't find Question with 'id'=1` citing the edit method in my Questions controller.

Here's the error:

```
Extracted source (around line #13):

11 </div>
12 <div class="col-md-8">
13   <%= form_for @question do |f| %>
14     <div class="form-group">
15       <%= f.label :title %>
16       <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder:        "Enter question title" %>
```

My controller:

```
 class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @questions = Question.all
  end

  def new
    @question = Question.new
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.new(params.require(:question).permit(:title, :body, :resolved))
      if @question.save
        flash[:notice] = "Question was saved."
        redirect_to @question
    else
       flash[:error] = "There was an error in saving your question. Please ask again."
        render :new
     end
  end

  def show
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @question = Question.new
  end

  def edit
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    if @question.update_attributes(params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body))
      flash[:notice] = "Post was updated."
      redirect_to @question
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end

   def create
    if      @question.update_attributes(params.require(:question).permit(:title, :body, :resolved))
      flash[:notice] = "Question was updated."
      render :edit
      redirect_to @question
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving your question. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def delete
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @question = Question.destroy
    redirect_to @question
  end
end
```

```

The view it's supposed to affect:

```
<h1><%= @question.title %></h1>

<p><%= @question.body %></p>

<%= link_to "Edit", edit_question_path(@question), class: 'btn btn-success' %>

<%= link_to "Delete", @question.delete, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
```

And my routes file:
    Rails.application.routes.draw do

```
  resources :posts
  resources :advertisements
  resources :questions
  resources :answers

  get 'about' => 'welcome#about'

  root to: 'welcome#index'
end
```

Any help you could give me would be much appreciated. I'm still kind of learning all of this.

You can view the repository for this project at https://github.com/InsomniaNoir/bloccit

Comment: are you shure you have a question whit `id = 1` in you database?

Comment: I seeded the database myself using Faker.

Comment: I agree with @inye - I'd just double check the DB. ;-)

Comment: The sqlite command line shows the database is there. The fact that I can also run a destroy method on an entry without throwing an error would tell me the  database is populated.

Comment: Is there a chance that you destroyed the question object that you are trying to edit?

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't make any sense. In my app you can either delete or edit. You can't do both. They both call for find(params[:id]) but only the delete function works.

Answer (score 1):

You have `<%= link_to "Delete", @question.delete, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>` on your show view. So every time you get your show view it executes @question.delete and it deletes that @question. If you don't believe me visit a question then refresh the page you will see that your @question has been deleted. Replace that code with `<%= link_to "Delete", @question, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>`. I saw that in your git repository you commented out the edit action don't forget to uncomment it.

Comment: What a quirky little issue. I had "edit" uncommented when I was running delete but didn't realize I had the link_to syntax wrong. It works just fine now.